# drop down content on a particular list

Tags: javascript, jquery

need help on this please

need this when click it slides down the content and when clicked again it slides up

```
<li>...</li>    
<li>...</li>
<li id="with-content"><a href="#">Click here</a>
<div class="content">Some div here Some div here Some div here</div>
</li>
```

only that particular list and not all list need to show content or hide with the slide effect

how can I do this with jquery? please any help would do, just a simple slidedown + slideup effect

Comment: Have you tried anything yet?

Comment: yes, but does not work

Comment: [slideUp](http://api.jquery.com/slideUp/) and [slideDown](http://api.jquery.com/slideDown/)

Answer (score 2):

This should be trivial to figure out with a search, and a little effort goes a long way, but I'll answer anyway:

```
$('#with-content a').on('click', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $(this).closest('li').find('.content').slideToggle(600);
});
```

ID's are unique, and it probably needs to be wrapped in document.ready and jQuery must be included on the site ?

Comment: Good call on the `preventDefault()`, some browsers shoot the scroll back to the top if you happen to be scrolled down.

Answer (score 0):

```
$('#with-content a').on('click', function(e) {
   e.preventDefault();
   $('#with-content').toggle();
});
```